# Thread safety when storing pointers to object in container

Tags: c++, pointers, thread-safety, containers

I have a question about good code practice when a mutex needs to be implemented. Consider the following code example where there is a manager class (Group) which holds a container of pointers to an object (Person).

If the Group class is shared by multiple threads, what is the correct method to access the public methods of the Person object?

Because when I execute 'getPerson()', I retrieve the pointer. But when I try and execute the 'getName()' it is possible the person object is already removed/deleted. How is this done the nice way?

EDIT: this example is not multi threaded, but consider this class used in multithreaded environment :)

```cpp
class Person 
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string place) :
    m_name(name),
    m_place(place) {};

    ~Person() {};

    std::string getName(){return m_name;}
    std::string getPlace(){return m_place;}

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_place;
};

class Group
{
public:
    Group() :
    m_persons(100) {};

    ~Group(){};

    void createPerson() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mtx);
        Person* p = new Person("John", "London");
        m_persons.push_back(p);
    }

    void removePerson(int index) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mtx);
        m_persons.erase(m_persons.begin() + index);
    }

    Person* getPerson(int index) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_mtx);
        return m_persons[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<Person*> m_persons;
    std::mutex m_mtx;

};

int main() {
   Group g();
   g.createPerson();
   g.createPerson();

   std::cout << g.getPerson(0).getName();
}
```

Comment: `removePerson` does not destroy any `Person`, so that's not a problem in itself. You do need to figure out how to manage the lifetime of `Person`s, though. Does the `Group` own them, or somebody else, or are they shared (and if they are, who gets to share them)?

Comment: I would say in this example, group owns them. Yes I quickly wrote this example and I also have a memory leak apparently. Lets say that removePerson also deletes the pointer. Is the only solution then to create helper methods in Group to access the public methods of Person safely?

Comment: Re, "I would say...group owns them." What happens when you decide later on that it must be possible for a single person to belong to more than one group? That's a very realistic possibility, and it's the kind of architectural thing where preparing for it early on could save you a _lot_ of re-writing later.

Answer (score 0):

> when I execute 'getPerson()', I retrieve the pointer. But when I try and execute the 'getName()' it is possible the person object is already removed/deleted.

The "already deleted" part sounds like a good use-case for `std::shared_ptr` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

If you use shared pointers everywhere, then you never explicitly delete an object: You allow the `shared_ptr` class to automatically delete it when (and only when) the last reference is destroyed or re-assigned.

That doesn't solve the problem of what it means for one thread to obtain a reference to a person via their membership in a particular group while another thread simultaneously removes that same person from the same group. That's a higher-level race condition that you probably can only prevent or cope with by implementing some appropriately high-level and *application-specific* policy.